# How to programmatically add discount to order total on magento 2

Tags: sales-order, discount

I need to programmatically add custom discount to order total on magento 2. This will work in such a way that when the customer inputs a code in the checkout page, a certain amount will be discounted from the order total

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/magepal/stackexchange/tree/develop/104112